# Swift: How can a superlayer have no sublayers?

Tags: ios, swift

[image: enter image description here console output]

How can a `superlayer` have no `sublayers`? Please see image above.

This is Xcode 6.3.

Comment: What about `halfShapeLayer!.superlayer.mask`?

Comment: Oooooh, @LeoNatan, tricky-wicky! Nice one. I never considered that. You should give that as an answer!

Comment: So here is a short Swift program that generates the situation @LeoNatan is hinting at: `let v = UIView(); let lay = CALayer(); v.layer.mask = lay` Now `lay.superlayer` is not nil, but `lay.superlayer!.sublayers` is nil.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, one case where a layer could be a superlayer but not have sublayers is when it has a [mask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/mask).

```
let layer = CALayer()
let mask = CALayer()
layer.mask = mask
```

Now `mask.superlayer` is `layer`, but `layer.sublayers` is nil.